# Logarithmic Factorization and Representation as Power of e

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

In some online math solution provider engines, sometimes equations are provided in a way which may be reducible to more understandable equations. Yet, they assume you know the concept in detail and shorten their solutions. My question regarding with that will be; how is the following equation possible, would you elaborate?

```
n^(logn)=e^((logn)^2)
```

Comment: Do you know the property that $e^{\ln n}=\ldots$?

Comment: Yes:), it should be equal to n

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way to see this is to take the natural logarithm of the equation.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\ln n \ln n = \ln e^{ (\ln(n))^2}
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have $$\log(n)\log(n)=(\log(n))^2$$ and it is $$x^{\alpha}=e^{\alpha\ln(x)}$$ for $x>0$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The latter equation is the essence I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

According to our little exchange in the comments, you know that $e^{\ln n}=n$. This and $\left(a^b\right)^c=a^{bc}$ are the key propertis to prove the given identity:
$$n^{\ln n}=\left(e^{\ln n}\right)^{\ln n}=e^{(\ln n)^2}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your elaboration!